# Error on module admin configuration page

Tags: 7

I cannot find any documentation or similar problem with mine.

Whenever I am trying to go to the configuration page of some installed module like "Pagetitle" module and Add menu links module.

The page is at unformatted layout, doesnt seem to load the css or javascript, and some links in the configuration page are not showing

Here is the screen shot of the configuration page of page title module (I am logged in as administrator).

I dont know whats causing this, I have disabled modules Im not using and updated the core files as well as all installed modules I can not configure the module.

Please any idea to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is because the page rendering stopped when an error occurred. By default, Drupal does not display such kind of errors.

Enable your error reporting by temporarily editing your index.php file (normally located in your root directory) directly after the first opening PHP tag to add the following:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

After you edited the file, run your site and see what error came out.

[WSOD](http://drupal.org/node/158043) is not directly related to this question, but it may be useful for you to tackle down your problem. It will help you to find out invisible errors.

Comment: or you can check the logs if its configured.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was able to display the error and this is Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 201326592 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 73 bytes) in /home/ssagroup/public_html/_training_site/sites/all/modules/token/token.pages.inc on line 228

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: I always add this lines to my settings.php - ini_set('max_execution_time', '3600');  ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); The later one will resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried to do what u advised Sithu but it didnt solve it. I got another error


> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 201326592 bytes exhausted (tried
> to allocate 262144 bytes) in
> /home/ssagroup/public_html/_training_site/includes/theme.inc on line
> 1962

I cant use pagetitle module :( is there any modulewith similar features?

Comment: This is the same issue for memory limit. Are you really add the code `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` in your sites/default/settings.php? You could also try any size greater than 512M such as 600M, 700M, etc. But 512M should resolve this.